# can't get hello, world program to work

Tags: d, codepad

I'm trying to get the hello, world program from [D (The Programming Language)/d2/Hello, World!](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/D_(The_Programming_Language)/d2/Hello,_World!) to work on codepad.org. Here's my code:

```
/* This program prints a
   hello world message
   to the console.  */

import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    writeln("Hello, World!");
}
```

Here's the output I get when I run it at http://codepad.org/MdLVQEMm:

```
Line 9: Error: undefined identifier writeln
Line 9: Error: function expected before (), not writeln of type int
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? I pretty much just copy / pasted the code..

Comment: Have you tried another environment? I don't know D, but this sounds like a dumb caching error. If you were using an IDE, it's tell you to clear its cache. Maybe clear the browser cache?

Comment: That code works on [IDEone.com](http://ideone.com/kC9wgS). Do you specifically need to use codepad.org or can you just use a different compiler?

Comment: I confirm the code is correct, the issue is specific to codepad.org

Comment: @JGreenwell - that helps - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From their [about page](http://codepad.org/about), codepad.org uses D version 1.026, which was [released in 2008](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/1.0/changelog.html#new1_026). For reference, the current version is 2.074.1.

It's unlikely that modern D code will work with such an old version of D, especially after a major version bump. You'll have to use a different service with updated tools.

Answer (score 3):

Use https://run.dlang.io for an online editor backed by an up-to-date compiler.